# "fast-fired litany"

Tags: meaning-in-context

In a biological conference, Artist Mark Dion presented an installation which was some kind of dictionary, displaying the meaning of certain words like Biocides, Caroline Parakeet, etc. which were all somehow in connection with human interventions in  nature. Sian Ede describing this artwork says

> Dion’s **fast-fired litany** is charged with energy and wit but, above
>   all, a sense of personal responsibility and desire for action. The
>   world doesn’t need more wringing of hands. It needs science.
>
> Sian Ede ([Art & Science](https://books.google.com/books?id=iiE3RsvK248C&pg=PA164&lpg=PA164&dq=%22Dion%E2%80%99s%20fast-fired%20litany%20is%22&source=bl&ots=Cu2-rjBlu5&sig=XUmiDwbWgxihHBxjAglNUxMJ6bc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAGoVChMI1JabuYmpyAIVwkIUCh0qtg9C#v=onepage&q=%22Dion%E2%80%99s%20fast-fired%20litany%20is%22&f=false))

1. Does "fast-fired" mean "harsh, stark, and straight"?
2. How about "litany"? Does it imply "the list of words" or in other words "Dion's dictionary"?

Comment: This is Sian Ede.  These words have no discernible meaning.  "Fired" could mean placed in a kiln, dismissed, launched a projectile, set alight.  Each of these make as much or as little sense as the others.  Here's part of the preceding sentence: ""[A]rtists who do engage with Nature can no longer regard it as a sublime route to the ineffable."  This is practically a private language, so you'll have to ask Ede what she meant.  This assumes she knows or could explain.  Realize that not all syntactically correct English makes sense.

Comment: The only time I've come across 'fast-fire' is in the context of 'fast-fire round', meaning a round of questions asked and answered quickly. Although, it would more often be 'quick-fire round'. But I agree with deadrat (+1) that it might just be deliberately opaque.

Comment: *Fast-fired litany* puts me in mind of "Only the stuttering rifles' rapid rattle // Can patter out their hasty orisons."

Answer (score 1):

[Litany](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/litany) is defined in Merriam-Webster as;

> a long list of complaints, problems, etc.

Fast-fired, based on the context above, means the litany (*a list of compliants about the fact that humans are not doing enough for environment/nature*) was expressed in a very enthusiastically high voice at a very fast pace.

The adjective, *fast*, is used when descibing a rate of a machine gun which **fires** multiple rounds of ammunition in a second.

"Fast-fired" is a metaphor to describe not only *his enthusiasm and energy in an effort to change the people's opinion on environment/nature*, but also *the way he expressed his opinion.*

Answer (score 0):

*Fast-fired* is another way of saying *rapid-fire*: "Delivered or coming in a rapid continuous stream" ([WordWeb online](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/RAPIDFIRE))